# Magento 2 Rest API Returning Net::HTTPRetriableError: 302 "Found"

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying get access token & access secret but when i try to connect to magento2 rest API i am getting this error, I have tried multiple endpoints urls like `rest/V1/`, `rest/all/V1/` etc but still get `Net::HTTPRetriableError: 302 "Found"`

Here is the code i am using to access the token

```
REQUEST_URL = '/oauth/token/request'
ACCESS_URL = '/oauth/token/access'
```

`OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, site: site, request_token_path: REQUEST_URL, access_token_path: ACCESS_URL)`

Can you please advice as to what could be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: you're passing wrong urls.

Comment: First get admin integration token

Comment: Hello Aditya, thanks for your reply.  I have updated the ticket with the code i use to get the tokens, I am using Oauth Consumer

Comment: Okay, did you get admin token ?

Comment: actually the above code works for other url but there is a specific magento store for which i am getting this Net::HTTPRetriableError: 302 "Found" error

Comment: Okay for admin token, you need to get it from admin panel.

Comment: and do you have POSTMAN application ?

Comment: Hi Aditya, yes, I have postman application, I have created a integration which has consumer key & consumer secret. I am unable to indentify what end point on server will return the correct access token & secret

Comment: great :) i am posting answer for end point, don't worry

Comment: that would be really great & helpfull, Thanks Aditya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83670/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-opensource-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Endpoint**

```
http://magento.host/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token
```

- `method : GET`

**Header**

```
Content-Type application/json
```

**Payload**

```
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "123123q"
}
```

**Response**

> Magento returns the admin’s access token.

- This token must be specified in the authorization header of every
  call that requires admin permissions.